# Install homebrew in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation

I'm trying to install homebrew on my Ubuntu.
I followed all [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160102025459/http://brew.sh/linuxbrew/) and used these commands:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

But when I run this:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

I get this error:

```
No command 'brew' found, did you mean:
Command 'qbrew' from package 'qbrew' (universe)
Command 'brec' from package 'bplay' (universe)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that you need these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
```

So, installing the above packages will solve your issue.

Comment: After execute above command. I am trying to execute "brew install pdftohtml" but still got brew command not found.

Answer (score 2):

Since Feb 2018, you install linuxbrew (=homebrew for linux) just by:

```
sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
```

Comment: Better said: Starting from Xenial (16.04). https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linuxbrew-wrapper

Comment: [Only on 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linuxbrew-wrapper)

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04, you can see this post here: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-on-Linux.md. Simply follow the instructions to add Homebrew to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

One more package is needed in addition to those mentioned in [Raphael's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/713810/527764)

> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
> ```

```
sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04, I used Alternative Installation

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin
ln -s ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin
eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Info:

https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Comment: From [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/): Paste that in a Linux shell prompt: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`. Usually running this kind of command isn't a good idea (unless you really trust the source).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this http://linuxbrew.sh/

**Install**

Paste at a terminal prompt:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```